# How separate Excel instance in case if one of workbook has autosave?

Tags: excel, vba, save, exit

Hello my workbooks is set:

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
ThisWorkbook.Windows(1).Visible = False

Call Starter.Show(vbModeless)

End Sub

Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(cancel As Boolean)
Workbooks("RMA_Manager.xlsm").Save
End Sub
```

But if I would like to close another Workbook (it is doesn't matter which workbook / file), also my Workbook with code and userform is saved and closed. The same if I would like to exit my workbook with code - anothers workbook are also closed.
I am not sure why, but is it possible to separete instances of Excel and working with workbooks independed?

Answer (score 0):

Here are two alternatives to open a new instance of Excel:

1- Open Excel from the Shell using the /x command

```
"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\EXCEL.EXE" /x
```

---

2- Open the workbook you're going to work with through VBA

```
Shell Application.Path & Application.PathSeparator & "excel.exe  /x " & "C:\PathToFile\FileName.xlsx"
```